# Was Spinoza an atheist?

Tags: metaphysics, atheism, spinoza

As I start to read Spinoza scholars, I am getting the impression that most believe that Spinoza was an atheist.  I can see their point.  If God is not conscious, not aware of individuals, and God's actions are not only predetermined but could not be any other way, then God is a machine and even though Spinoza talks about God, he is really just talking about a living universe more than a living Deity. In [Tractatus Theologico-Politicus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractatus_Theologico-Politicus), he treats the Bible as any other human document which shows that has no trouble denying its sanctity.

The authors that lead me to this viewpoint are [Steven Nadler](https://press.princeton.edu/ideas/spinozas-guide-to-life-and-death) and [Edwin Curley](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/069102037X).  Am I misunderstanding their viewpoint?

I have trouble accepting this point about Spinoza.  If Spinoza was an atheist, why would God be such a central part of Spinoza's philosophy. Even if he rejects Christianity and Judaism as belief systems, hasn't he proposed his own, incredibly well-thought out deist metaphysics?  I keep thinking that if God has thought, then God is conscious.  If God is conscious, then Spinoza is not an atheist.

Are there any major Spinoza scholars who believe that Spinoza was not an atheist?  I would be very interested in reading a different viewpoint when I finish Nadler and Curley.

---

**Update**: Found a great answer to my question in this Wikipedia article on [pantheism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantheism).

Thanks to Mauro Allegranza for his comments!

Comment: For sure, Spinoza's God is not the god of Christian and Jewish religione.

Comment: I understand. But there are other options besides Christianity, Judaism, or atheism. Spinoza appears to me to be arguing for a spiritual, conscious God that is the foundation of existence.  I understand that my view may not be supported by current scholarship.  Is there any Spinoza scholar who believes that Spinoza was not an atheist?

Comment: The usual reading of S is: pantheism. For S's contemporary readers he was an atheist.

Comment: Thanks, Mauro.  Appreciate it.  I'll read up more on pantheism so I am clear.  :-)

Comment: IMO -isms are not so relevant. What is fundamental is that for S the Bible is a human-written historical text. This caused him to be banned as *heretical*.

Comment: The question of whether Spinoza saw God as conscious seems to be uncertain, in part because early modern philosophy didn't distinguish between functional aspects of consciousness and phenomenal consciousness/qualia the way current analytic philosophy of mind tends to do (for ex. Descartes didn't say 'I am conscious, therefore I am'). Found an interesting [paper](https://willamette.edu/undergraduate/philosophy/past-colloquia/nwpc-2010/roelofs.pdf) that talks about this question, it suggests that translated into modern terms, Spinoza's God may be the true subject of *all* phenomenal experience.

Comment: Relevant: MICHAEL A. ROSENTHAL, [WHY SPINOZA IS INTOLERANT OF ATHEISTS (2012)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41635521)